# Mysql After Insert trigger to check new value

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables:

1. oee_main
2. oee_client

I already have an after insert trigger on oee_main as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `oee_upd` AFTER INSERT ON `oee_main`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE oee_client
    SET END_DATE= NOW()  where END_DATE IS NULL
```

I now need to develop the trigger even more so that the newly inserted row in oee_main will not only update the END_DATE of oee_client to NOW() where END_DATE is NULL but to only update the row(s) of oee_client where the column called Machine_ID is equal to the newly inserted column named NAME in oee_main.

I have tried adding this to the where condition of the above trigger to no success:

```
where END_DATE IS NULL and Machine_ID = new.`oee_main`.`NAME`
```

Therefore what I am after is that when a new record is inserted in oee_main which has a value of for example '2' in column 'NAME' the trigger updates only the columns END_DATE of oee_client where NULL and where Machine_ID of oee_client is equal to the newly inserted value of NAME in oee_main.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the logic you want:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `oee_upd` AFTER INSERT ON `oee_main`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE oee_client c
        SET c.END_DATE = NOW()  
        WHERE c.END_DATE IS NULL AND c.Machine_ID = new.NAME;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Remember to use the `delimiter` statement whenever you define triggers, stored procedures and functions.  It will help prevent errors in the future.

As for your error, you don't need to mention the table name when you use `NEW`.

As an outsider, I find it confusing that `NAME` in one table matches `MACHINE_ID` in another table.  I would expect both tables to have a column called `MACHINE_ID`.